# porting app.config to save settings in mono

Tags: linux, configuration, mono

I am trying to run an application in linux using mono, Application works fine but i cannot save the settings since the app.config uses userSettings of type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="howto_save_restore_settings.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <howto_save_restore_settings.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Left" serializeAs="String">
                <value>100</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Top" serializeAs="String">
                <value>100</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Width" serializeAs="String">
                <value>300</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Height" serializeAs="String">
                <value>300</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Contents" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </howto_save_restore_settings.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have attached the app.config file for your reference
Can anyone suggest me or guide me so that the settings can be saved in Linux using mono

Comment: To really save your time, migrate to .NET Core.

Comment: can you suggest me how to migrate to .NET Core, does mono(OS:- Linux support it)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ Forgot about Mono please.

Comment: Settings work fine in windows i want run this application in linux using mono